# How to avoid checking for None when setting Optional dataclass args in __post_init__

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-dataclasses

Consider a dataclass with a mutable default value for an argument. To be able to instantiate an object with a new default value and not a shared mutable object, we can do something like:

```
@dataclass
class ClassWithState:
    name: str
    items: Optional[List[str]] = None

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if self.items is None:
            self.items = []
```

This works as expected. However, whenever I refer to `items` in some instance of this class, mypy warns that `items` may be None. For example:

```
c = ClassWithState("object name")
c.items.append("item1")
```

MyPy will complain with something like:

> Item "None" of "Optional[List[str]]" has no attribute "append".

I don't want to have to add unnecissary checks every time I refer to `items` such as

```
assert c.items is not None
```

everywhere I refer to `items`. How can I convince mypy that `items` will never be None?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [`field`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) with the `default_factory` option set:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List


@dataclass
class ClassWithState:
    name: str
    items: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)

>>> ClassWithState("Hello")
ClassWithState(name='Hello', items=[])
```

Comment: doesn't this model set the default to an empty list, not None?  What if you want a default to be None, rather than an empty list?
I'm curious how to handle this, because the `Optional` defaulting to None - by typing's view of the world - seems to be 'standard', but it does cause mypy problems because `None` doesn't match your declared type.

Comment: @Richard Yes. I'm "reading between the lines" in this answer, and assumed that the OP was using `None` as a placeholder, and that they actually wanted something else (which appears to have been the case). You're saying you want the field to be of type `Optional[Something]`, but don't want type errors when you try to use the field in a non-optional context?

Comment: Mostly it's because of convenience and brevity.  Convenience because you can check if a field is 'set' by simple `if ClassWithState.items: do_something` and not have it through an exception if the field isn't defined (Much shorter then wrapping in a `hasattr()`).  Brevity because a lot of what I use them for results in me dumping the structures into json.  The json encoder I'm using will skip anything with `None`, but for empty lists etc it would dump that as an empty list.

Comment: @Richard You should be able to avoid mypy errors using `if your_optional` or `if your_optional is not None:` before use. Something like `return your _optional and your_optional.value_to_use` should work too due to how `and` works. Really, if you're using Optional, you should do a check for safety. In langusges like Haskell where this pattern originated, it's actually a compile-time error to not handle `None` `Optional` case.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do.  I just would prefer not to, as while it makes for typesafe, mypy passing code, it does add an indent and another line to everywhere I want to use it  ...however it is the correct thing to do and what I've been moving to.

Answer (score 4):

#### The problem (and what if we need more flexibility?)

The issue is that we don't have any way to tell mypy that `items` will be Optional before `__post_init__` but not afterward.

Carcigenicate's [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64670403/3780389) handles the case when the desired default initialization doesn't depend on other parameters of the initializer. However, let say that you need to look at `name` in order to know how to default-initialize `items`.

For this scenario, it would be great if there were an analog to the `default_factory` method that took in the parameters to the partially initialized object as a parameter, but unfortunately [there is no such analog](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field). Other things that might look related but don't serve the purpose:

- The `init=False` field option which allows the field to be initialized in `__post_init__` but removes the option of the user specifying an explicit value.
- Using the `InitVar` generic type does the opposite of what we want here: makes the value available to the initializer (and `__post_init__`) without including it as a field of the dataclass object.

#### Using a non-None *sentinel* value

However, as a work-around, you can designate a special object value to represent to the `__post_init__` method that the field's default value needs to be replaced.  For most types, it is easy to just create a unique dummy object of the particular type which you can store as a class variable and return from the field default_factory (if it is a mutable type like `list`, dataclass won't let you assign it directly as the default value).  For types like `str` and `int` this won't be guaranteed to work as expected unless you use a "change_me" value that you *know* won't be a legitimate explicit value for the field.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import ClassVar, List


@dataclass
class ClassWithState:
    name: str
    __uninitialized_items: ClassVar[List[str]] = list()
    items: List[str] = field(default_factory=lambda: ClassWithState.__uninitialized_items)

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if self.items is self.__uninitialized_items:
            self.items = [str(i) for i in range(len(self.name))]


print(ClassWithState("testing", ["one", "two", "three"]))
print(ClassWithState("testing"))
print(ClassWithState("testing", []))
```

Output:

```
ClassWithState(name='testing', items=['one', 'two', 'three'])
ClassWithState(name='testing', items=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
ClassWithState(name='testing', items=[])
```

#### If the field can have a slightly different name ...

##### Using properties

*If* you do not require passing explicit initialization by name (or even if you can simply let the parameter have a slightly different name from the name use you when asserting non-None), then [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) are an even more flexible option.
The idea is to have the Optional field be a separate (possibly even a "private") member while having a property give access to a version that is automatically cast.  I came across this solution for a situation where I needed to apply additional transformations whenever the object was accessed and casting is just a special case (the ability to have the property be read-only is nice as well). (You can consider `cached_property` if the object reference will never change.)

Here's an example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Optional, cast


@dataclass
class ClassWithState:
    name: str
    _items: Optional[List[str]] = None

    @property
    def items(self) -> List[str]:
        return cast(List[str], self._items)

    @items.setter
    def items(self, value: List[str]) -> None:
        self._items = value

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if self._items is None:
            self._items = [str(i) for i in range(len(self.name))]


print(ClassWithState("testing", _items=["one", "two", "three"]))
print(ClassWithState("testing", ["one", "two", "three"]))
print(ClassWithState("testing", []))
print(ClassWithState("testing"))

obj = ClassWithState("testing")
print(obj)
obj.items.append('test')
print(obj)
obj.items = ['another', 'one']
print(obj)
print(obj.items)
```

And the output:

```
ClassWithState(name='testing', _items=['one', 'two', 'three'])
ClassWithState(name='testing', _items=['one', 'two', 'three'])
ClassWithState(name='testing', _items=[])
ClassWithState(name='testing', _items=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
ClassWithState(name='testing', _items=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
ClassWithState(name='testing', _items=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'test'])
ClassWithState(name='testing', _items=['another', 'one'])
['another', 'one']
```

##### Make an `InitVar[Optional[...]]` field and use `__post_init__` to set the true field

Another alternative if you can handle a different name is to use `InitVar` to specify that the Optional version is just a parameter to `__init__` (and `__post_init__`) and then to set a different, non-optional, member variable within `__post_init__`. This avoids needing to do any casting, doesn't require setting up a property, allows the representation to use the target name rather than the surrogate name, and doesn't risk the problem of not having a reasonable sentinel value, but, again, it only works if you can handle an initializer parameter with a different name from the access field and it is less flexible than the property approach:

```py
from dataclasses import InitVar, dataclass, field
from typing import List, Optional


@dataclass
class ClassWithState:
    name: str
    _items: InitVar[Optional[List[str]]] = None
    items: List[str] = field(init=False, default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self, items: Optional[List[str]]) -> None:
        if items is None:
            items = [str(i) for i in range(len(self.name))]
        self.items = items
```

The usage is the same as the property approach, and the output would also look the same except that the representation wouldn't have the underscore in front of `items`.